# Is Counter-Strike 1.6 cross compatible with other platforms?

Tags: steam, macos, counter-strike

I would like to know if I buy CS 1.6 on Steam, then will I be able to play with stand-alone CS 1.6 on Windows computers via LAN/Wifi?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks. I've removed that part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Counter Strike 1.6 on Steam is currently cross platform on Windows, Mac OS X and SteamOS+Linux.

It is interoperable between all platforms, so you should have no problems playing with friends on a LAN.

Comment: Thanks. I know that CS on Steam is cross-platform, but my friends only have stand-alone CS and not Steam CS (i.e. they installed CS without Steam). I'm new to Steam and do not really know how it works :(